# sed search line and replace only text in that line

Tags: linux, sed

i want to use sed to replace any x(small) to 0 if the line contains Z(capital)

```
x,Z,y
y,X,z,
Y,z,x
x,Z,y
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ sed '/Z/s/x/0/g' <input_file>
```